# React theme not applied to children components

Tags: reactjs

This is my first interaction with React, the code is below:

```
header.jsx

import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            logged: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppBar title="Some title"
                iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
                iconElementRight={this.state.logged ? <Logged /> : <Login />} />
        );
    }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FlatButton label="Login" />
        );
    }
}

class Logged extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <IconMenu iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
                targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
                anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}>
                <MenuItem primaryText="Item1" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Item2" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Item2" />
            </IconMenu>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;


index.jsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';

import Header from './header.jsx';

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

injectTapEventPlugin();

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <p> Hello React!</p>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The problem is that the theme is applied to the AppBar only and not to its components, that are  and , this is what i got:
[image]

However, if I change the Header component by adding the code from  component directly in the AppBar component, like this:

```
<AppBar title="Some title"
                iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
                iconElementRight={this.state.logged ? <Logged /> : <FlatButton label="Login" />} />
```

the result is different:

Could you please tell me what am I missing in order for the theme to be  propagated to the child components and why does it work in the second scenario?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppBar internal implementation checking type of the element provided to `iconElementRight` property. Theme will be provided 'automatically' just of case of explicit match type to some predefined values, like **FlatButton** for your example.

Here is how this works internally (taken from material-ui/AppBar source code):

```
// around 239 line
if (iconElementRight) {
  var iconElementRightProps = {};

  switch (iconElementRight.type.muiName) {
    case 'IconMenu':
    case 'IconButton':
      var iconElemRightChildren = iconElementRight.props.children;
      var _iconButtonIconStyle = !(iconElemRightChildren && iconElemRightChildren.props && iconElemRightChildren.props.color) ? styles.iconButtonIconStyle : null;

      iconElementRightProps.iconStyle = (0, _simpleAssign2.default)({}, _iconButtonIconStyle, iconElementRight.props.iconStyle);
      break;

    case 'FlatButton':
      iconElementRightProps.style = (0, _simpleAssign2.default)({}, styles.flatButton, iconElementRight.props.style);
      break;

    default:
  }
```

As you can see, if you providing some custom component you need to apply styles to match theme manually, for example with context:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <FlatButton style={{
        color: this.context.muiTheme.appBar.textColor
      }}/>
    )
  }
}

Login.contextTypes = {
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```